# Jquery UI Autocomplete: is "value" required?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI's autocomplete with a remote data file. It works but it's slow. My JSONP is over a meg of 'value' junk characters and I'd like to minimize that. Here is the format:

```
[{"value": "Aaronsburg, PA"}, 
 {"value": "Abanda, AL"},
 {"value": "Abbeville, AL"}]
```

How do I get jQuery UI's Autocomplete to accept a remote data file of the form:

```
{["Aaronsburg, PA", "Abanda, AL", "Abbeville, AL"]}
```

or

```
["Aaronsburg, PA", "Abanda, AL", "Abbeville, AL"]
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) can take any format of data. You have complete control the rendering of the list but in this case I think it might just work.

[**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mujs2/1/) (albeit with a local source) seems to work as expected.

If you need more control you can tailor the renderItem function to suit any data format:

```
var searches = [{
    label:'first',
    desc:'foo foo',
},
{
    label:'second',
    desc:'bar bar',
},
{
    label:'third',
    desc:'baz baz',
}];

$(function() {
    $('input').autocomplete({
      dataType: 'json',
      source: searches
    })
    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>')
       .data('item.autocomplete', item)
       .append(item.desc)
       .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Or there is an [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) on the jQuery site using remote JSONP as a source and customizes the `label` and `value` needed to populate the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I can think of to do this is by using php with fopen and fread, then format the data.